# I Installed Material Design in Angular 9, why can't I get the elements to show?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an existing Angular 9 project that I'm trying to add the Material library to. However, I can't seem to get any of the elements to show and keep getting this error

```
core.js:14613 'mat-icon' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

I'm wondering what I might be missing! I have tried altering the versions of my dependencies, and importing all the modules, but would appreciate any help at all!

Here is my app.module

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppConfigService } from './services/app-config.service';
import { AppInitializer } from './services/app-initializer.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DeviceModule } from './device/device.module';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { GatewayModule } from './gateway/gateway.module';
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LogoModule } from './logo/logo.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import {  MatProgressSpinnerModule, MatProgressSpinner } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    DeviceModule,
    GatewayModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    LogoModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([]),
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
  providers: [
    AppConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: AppInitializer,
      multi: true,
      deps: [AppConfigService]
    },
    {
      provide: LocationStrategy,
      useClass: HashLocationStrategy
    },
    FormBuilder,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here are the dependencies from my package.json

```
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^9.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.11.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
  },
```

Comment: It seems like you're missed to add the `MatIconModule` import in feature module that this component html is a part of.

Answer (score 0):

## In Angular 9 versions and above

**You should import `MatIconModule` to your app.module.ts file. You are missing `MatIconModule` in you app.module.ts**

```
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon'
```

**And In your app.module.ts imports array use it like this :**

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppConfigService } from './services/app-config.service';
import { AppInitializer } from './services/app-initializer.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DeviceModule } from './device/device.module';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { GatewayModule } from './gateway/gateway.module';
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LogoModule } from './logo/logo.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import {  MatProgressSpinnerModule, MatProgressSpinner } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    MatIconModule, // <-- Include it here
    MatButtonModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    DeviceModule,
    GatewayModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    LogoModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([]),
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
  providers: [
    AppConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: AppInitializer,
      multi: true,
      deps: [AppConfigService]
    },
    {
      provide: LocationStrategy,
      useClass: HashLocationStrategy
    },
    FormBuilder,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: `MatIconModule` is actually included if you'd scrolled down a bit, located under the `ReactiveFormsModule`.

Comment: Can you add the stackblitz for your example